# Multiple legacy sequences to one hibernate sequence

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate

I'm moving from Ruby On Rails  to Spring Boot, and I am working on database moves. I was using PostgreSQL and is planning to use same DBMS on new framework.

My DB from Ruby On Rails has multiple sequences, each for each own table (e.g. `user_id_seq`).

I want to use only one sequence `hibernate_sequence`.

Would there be any way to move multiple sequences into one `hibernate_sequence`?

Comment: Isn't `hibernate_sequence` a table that tries to fake real sequences for database systems that don't have efficient native sequences?

Comment: In the postgres file tree, it appears under the directory `sequences`, while other tables are under `tables` directory.